# Manage scope of variables on destructing of an objecct

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using an external API which return an object for every API call like below.

For successful resonse.

```
{
 error: null,
 data: {
 //response fields
 }
}
```

For unsuccessfull response.

```
{
 error: {
 //error fields
 }
 data: null
}
```

I am using these API in my controller, like below.

```
const verifyPayment = async function() {
  const {error, data} = await Service.fetchOrder()
  if(error)
      return false
  const {error, data} = await Service.verifyPayment()
  if(error)
     return false
  return true
}
```

I know I can't declare or overwrite a variable with `const` in same scope.
I also can not do the same with `let`

I tried declaring `error` and `data` first, and then tried to overwrite but It's not working either.

```
let error
let data
{error, data} = await Service.fetchOrder()
```

One thing I also can do is wrapping those in a `try catch or if` block but that's unnecessary.
*Can someone suggest a workaround or any other pattern?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable can be assigned its value with destructuring separate from its declaration like:

```js
let error, data;
({error, data} = {error: null, data: 1});
console.log(error, data);

({error, data} = {error: 1, data: null});
console.log(error, data);
```

Notes from [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

> **Notes:** The parentheses `( ... )` around the assignment statement are required when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> `{a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}` is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the `{a, b}` on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, `({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2})` is valid, as is `const {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}`
>
> Your `( ... )` expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may be used to execute a function on the previous line.

Comment: This is some extra information, but the problem is this _Your ( ... ) expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may ....._

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

```
const verifyPayment = async function() {
    let response;
    response = await Service.fetchOrder()
    if(response.error)
        return false
    response = await Service.verifyPayment()
    if(response.error)
       return false
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring variables limits the variable usage to their primarily assigned values, therefore, they are not expected to be modified later in your code.

Think of them as "use once and discard" variables.

Then again, a solution is within the horizon: Renaming them.

(1) How do we do this?

```
const { data: data1, error: error1  } = await Service.fetchOrder();

if (error1) return false;

const { data: data2, error: error2 } = await Service.verifyOrder();

if (error2) return false;
```

This way your code will remain elegantly formatted and also facilitates debugging in case one of the call fails (knowing that the data was corrupted/invalid when it was named data1 is way better than simply tracking all instances where the value of the same-named variable was changed).

:)

Answer (score 0):

You can also destructure and put it into another variable.

```js
let { error: orderError, data: orderData} = {error: null, data: 1};
console.log(orderError, orderData);

let { error: payError, data: payData} = {error: 1, data: null};
console.log(payError, payData);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help in separation of concerns for both error and data variables, making it cleaner and concise.

```
const verifyPayment = async function() {
  const { error: fetchError, data: fetchData } = await Service.fetchOrder()
  if(fetchError)
      return false
  const { error: verifyError, data: verifyData } = await Service.verifyPayment()
  if(verifyError)
     return false
  return true
}
```